# Problems making query using accents PDO

Tags: pdo, diacritics, collate

I have the following problem:

I reated the following db and table:

```
CREATE DATABASE `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabCCs` ( `Cod` int(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE, `Nome1` varchar(20)  NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`Cod`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I made a batch file (.sql) to load the content:

```
INSERT INTO `tabCCs` (`Cod`, `Nome1`) VALUES (1,'Entrada'),(2,'Saída');
```

I checked via phpmyadmin and it is OK

For my WebService my PDO initiation is:

```
 PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
,PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
```

I also make queries (SELECT *) from my web in PDO and show ok.

```
$stm = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tabCCs');
$stm->execute();
```

When I add a WHERE clause, works well only for $value='Entrada' but doesn't for $value='Saída'.

```
$stm = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tabCCs WHERE Nome1 LIKE :value');
$stm->bindParam(':value', $value,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->execute();
```

Using $value='Saída' returns EMPTY.

I know it sounds like a Collate problem, But I don't have problem to INSERT accents using PDO or problems with returns that contain accents (SELECT * return the value Saída without problem).

Any suggestion? I looked all over internet and only find problems about exibition problems or incomplete inserts, but none for queries.

Thanks in advance!